# How to display an X on a board created using for loops by clicking on a square

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, tic-tac-toe

I'm a beginner so please be merciful :) 
I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game with html, css and pure JS. I'm stuck at trying to display an "X" symbol (or "O" ) while clicking on a square on my board (i used for loops for it, as i used it before for tetris game). I tried event listeners but couldn't get it to work, probably i'm doing something wrong :P So anyway my question is: How to display a symbol on a board by clicking on it ?

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tic-tac-toe.css">
    <title>TIC TAC TOE IN JS</title>
    <h1 class='header'>TIC TAC TOE in JS</h1>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class='canvas'>
        <canvas id="canvas" width='300px' height="300px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class='scores'>
        <div>Player 1 Wins: <span id="score-x">0</span></div>
        <div>Ties: <span id="score-tie">0</span> </div>
        <div>Player 2 Wins: <span id="score-o">0</span> </div>
    </div>

<script src="./tictactoe.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//CONSTS
const row = 3;
const col = 3;
const vacant = "white";
const sq = 100;
let w = canvas.clientWidth/3;
let h = canvas.clientHeight/3;


//draw a square
function drawSquare(x, y, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x*sq, y*sq, sq, sq);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.strokeRect(x*sq, y*sq, sq, sq);
}

    //Create board

let board = [ ];
for(let r = 0; r < row; r++){
    board[r] = [ ];
        for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            board[r][c] = vacant;
        }
}
    //Draw Board

function drawBoard() {
    for(r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(c = 0; c < col; c++){
            drawSquare(c, r, board[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
drawBoard();

//players
const players = ['X', 'O']
const player1 = players[0];
const player2 = players[1];

//let the starting player be selected at random
const spot = board[r-1][c-1];

function setup() {
    let randomPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() *2 );
    let currentPlayer = "";
    if (randomPlayer == 0){
        currentPlayer = player1;
        alert('Player 1 starts the game !')
    }else {
        currentPlayer = player2;
        alert('Player 2 starts the game !')
    };
}
function drawSymbol () {
    let x = w * r + w/2;
    let y = h * c + h/2;
    let xr = w/4;
    spot.addEventListener('click', (x, y, xr) => {
    line(x-xr, y-xr, x+xr, y+xr);
    line(x+xr, y-xr, x-xr, y+xr);
})
}


setup();
//Check if player clicked on the board 

//Place X

//Place O
```

UPDATED CODE

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Variables
let row = 3;
let col = 3;
const vacant = "white";
let sq = 100;
let w = canvas.clientWidth/3;
let h = canvas.clientHeight/3;
let currentPlayer = "";

//players
const players = ['X', 'O']
const player1 = players[0];
const player2 = players[1];


//draw a square
function drawSquare(x, y, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x*sq, y*sq, sq, sq);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.strokeRect(x*sq, y*sq, sq, sq);
}

//Create board
let board = [ ];
for(let r = 0; r < row; r++){
    board[r] = [ ];
        for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            board[r][c] = vacant;
        }
}
//Draw Board
function drawBoard() {
    for(r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(c = 0; c < col; c++){
            drawSquare(c, r, board[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
drawBoard();



// sets up the game
function setup() {

    //let the starting player be selected at random
    let randomPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() *2 );
    if (randomPlayer == 0){
        currentPlayer = player1;
        alert('Player 1 starts the game !')
    }else {
        currentPlayer = player2;
        alert('Player 2 starts the game !')
    };

    function calculatePos () {
        // checks for click position
        canvas.addEventListener('click', event => {

            // get the position of the board relative to the page
            let {left, top} = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            // get the position of the click relative to the page
            let mouseX = event.clientX - left;
            let mouseY = event.clientY - top;

            // calculate which square is being clicked 
            let newRow = Math.floor(mouseY / sq);
            let newCol = Math.floor(mouseX / sq);
            drawSymbol(newRow, newCol)
        })  
    }




calculatePos();
}
setup();
// listens for clicks on the canvas to draw the symbol
function drawSymbol (newRow, newCol) {
    let x = w * newRow + w/2;
    let y = h * newCol + h/2;
    let xr = w/4;
    if(currentPlayer == players[0]) {
        canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x-xr, y-xr);
            ctx.lineTo(x+xr, y+xr);
            ctx.moveTo(x+xr, y-xr);
            ctx.lineTo(x-xr, y+xr);
            ctx.stroke();
    }) 
    } else {
            canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
                ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x , y, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
    }
)}
}
drawSymbol(r, c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good so far! One way to accomplish this is to add the event listener to the *entire canvas element*. An appropriate place to add it is in your `setup` function; that way, as soon as the board is setup, your canvas will be listening for clicks.

Now, if the entire canvas is listening for clicks, you will need a way to determine which square has been clicked. This is not too difficult, but there are some snags. Let's imagine trying to determine this for a "1 dimensional board":

```
"The board"
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Suppose a click occurs somewhere on it:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
             ^click
|------------| <-clickPos = the distance between the click and the edge of the board
```

How can we determine which cell it occurred in? If we know the size of each cell, and the location of the click, it can be done with division:

```
const clickedCell = Math.floor(clickPos / cellSize);
```

We floor this value in order to produce an integral value (it will be 0 for the first cell, 1 for the second, etc.).

Here is where the "gotcha" shows up: when a click event occurs, it is easy to extract the location of the click *relative to the page*, but this is not necessarily what you want.

Here's a new "board" that reflects this:

```
|            +---------+---------+---------+
^ edge                    ^click
of page                   |
|-------------------------| <-this distance is easy to extract from the event
             |------------| <-this is the distance you want
|------------| <-this is the distance between the edge of the board and the edge of the page
```

As the diagram shows, the click position that we care about is actually not the one recorded in the event. In order to determine that, we need to subtract the position of the click from the position of the left edge of the board.

Here's how that looks in JavaScript:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
  const { left, top } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  //      ^^^^  ^^^ These give us the position of the board relative to the page
  const mouseX = event.clientX - left;
  const mouseY = event.clientY - top;
  //                   ^^^^^^^ These give us the position of the click relative to the page

  const row = Math.floor(mouseY / sq);
  const col = Math.floor(mouseX / sq);

  // Now draw your "X" or "O" here, using the `row` and `col` values
  // calculated above to determine where to place it
});
```

As a reminder, you only need to add that event listener once; once it's been added, it will call the function that we've provided every time a click occurs. It might make sense to break up the position-calculating work into a separate function, etc. but you will figure this out as you go. Hope this helps; keep it up!

Comment: You're welcome! Best of luck, and don't hesitate to reach out.

Comment: Alright, you are getting somewhere! If you are seeing the correct coordinates in the console, then you are one step closer. One way to proceed is like this: think about your `console.log` statement as a kind of "effect" that uses the cell coordinates; now, drawing an "X" or "O" is just another kind of "effect" that needs the cell coordinates. Consider trying the following: move your `drawSymbol` function to the "top level" (outside of any other functions), and modify it to take the row and column as parameters. Then, replace your existing `console.log` statement with a call to this function.

Comment: Let me know if that makes sense, or if you need a little more to go on.

Comment: It does makes sense, i have updated code again and used row and col as parameters in drawSymbol function as well as called it within calculatePos function. Now in the drawSymbol function both parameters are grayed out which means their value is never read and calling calculatePos(row, col) inside drawSymbol does not make it work either, what am i missing here ?

Comment: You are exactly right: your text editor is greying out the parameters since they are not used. Your `drawSymbol` function needs to make use of this information in order to draw an "O" or "X" (whichever is appropriate). It looks like you've already gotten a start with this, for instance by calculating the center of the cell and naming its coordinates `x` and `y`; however, this calculation makes use of two names `r` and `c` which should be replaced with the names of your parameters (`row` and `column`). Also, you can remove the `addEventListener` bit from this function (you've already handled >>

Comment: that below). Maybe start out by drawing something really simple, like a rectangle, in your `drawSymbol` function. Then, once you can do that, you will be confident in any changes you make in order to get it to draw the more complex "X" and "O". Let me know how that goes!

Comment: So i discovered that it was actually drawing something but it was out of the canvas, let me explain:
```let x = w * r + w/2;
   let y = h * c + h/2;```
both of these are calculated on basis that r and c is maximum (3) so the end result is 350, then if i click anywhere on the screen it draws it in a wrong place. And just as i was writing that i got enlightened and changed (r) and (c) in above variables to what it should be ! Right, it's  drawing X's and O's on the board but it does it randomly, sometimes where i click sometimes not, also needs a double click, i guess it's two event listeners

Comment: But if i delete one i can't draw again ... im updating the code above

Comment: ok i sorted out randomness of X placement - swapped newRow and newCol in let x... let y... variables
Now to sort out double click ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to never add an event listener to the canvas itself?
From such an event listener you can get the X and Y coordinates of the click to determine which cell was click. If that cell is vacant, draw a symbol for the current player.

So you'd need to make your drawSymbol take information about which cell to draw in.

You create a spot variable which I don't understand what it does, and inside drawSymbol you add a event listener to that but that likely isn't a element? And the drawSymbol function is never called so the code isn't executed so you don't get an error either.

Comment: Ahh sorry i was trying stuff out and forgot the change it back to my first "guess". It was suppose to be without the spot variable and instead of spot.addEventListener it was supposed to be canvas.addEventListener :) True that i didn't call drawSymbol function, but well, i was after hours of brainstorming how to write it :P  I will later try to draw using mouse coordinates and see how it goes, thanks :)